# use a generated jar from build plugin pom.xml as a dependency in the same pom

Tags: java, maven

This might sound strange but I have a pom file where a jar file is generated from the build plugin section, I wonder could I use this generated jar file as a dependency in the same pom as well? Below is the plugin section which a jar file(jkl.jar) will be generated.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="/_build/" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${xyz.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-jar</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        ...
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Could I use jkl.jar as a dependency in the same pom?i.e.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/_build/jkl.jar</systemPath>
<dependency>
```

I tried to set build plugin to build this jar at validate time with no avail, maven complains it couldn't find java package in that jar file.

I know that there is another way to do it, create a sub-module before running this pom.xml and use the generated jar from sub-module as a dependency in this pom.xml

I wonder is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please show your pom file..

Comment: @khmarbaise Please see my pom file

Comment: For me this action doesn't make any sense. Could you explain why do you need that?

Comment: It looks you misunderstanding the concept of maven. I don't understand your dependency with systemPath which absolute no sense to me ? Apart from that this is not the full pom file...